# 3D to 4D Matrix conversion Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a `m x n x p` 3D matrix available where, `m x n` are 2D images (row * columns), and `p` is the number of images.

I need to make this matrix 4D such that the new dimensions are `m x n x 1 x p`. The third dimension is constant for each of the images.

How can I do this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A call to [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) should do the trick.  Supposing that your image is stored in `A`, just do:

```
B = permute(A, [1 2 4 3]);
```

This transforms your matrix, which is `m x n x p`, to a matrix with a singleton third dimension while changing the third dimension from the original matrix so that it now becomes the fourth dimension.